# Spinoza Definitions VIII

Tags: spinoza

Please which of the meanings CONCEIVED is used in this context:
VIII By Eternity, I mean existence itself, in so far as it is conceived necessarily to follow solely from the definition of that which is eternal.

CONCEIVE -

1. To become pregnant with (offspring): She conceived her first child in London, but her second child was conceived in Paris.
2. To form or develop in the mind: conceive a plan to increase profits; conceive a passion for a new acquaintance.
3. To apprehend mentally; understand: couldn't conceive the meaning of that sentence.
4. To be of the opinion that; think: didn't conceive that such a tragedy could occur.
5. To begin or originate in a specific way: a political movement that was conceived in the ferment of the 1960s.
   v.intr.
6. To form or hold an idea: Ancient peoples conceived of the earth as flat.
7. To become pregnant

Comment: It may help to give the example of the usage...

Comment: "Conceiving" is the activity of the mind; compare with "perceive". We may rephrase it as "To understand something truly." Thus, I would chose 3) **understand**.

Comment: Thank you - is it safe then to assume that when "conceive" is used in Spinoza's The Ethics (I have a translation by R.H.M. Elwes) / or as in the original text, "concipio" - that most likely it is used with the meaning "to understand"?

Comment: @AlliJ- what Spinoza intends by the word 'conceive', is roughly, 'for that particular idea to have a presence in a human mind.' The mind and what it is capable of 'conceiving' share a reciprocal symbiotic relationship such that,  if a human mind is capable of conceiving eternity then that 'proves' that eternity exists necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Conceiving" is the activity of the mind (compare it with "perceive").

We may rephrase it as "To understand, to think something truly." Thus, I would chose 3. **understand**.

Understanding is the "basic" act of mind. The term is from Descartes; see [Meditations, V, 9](http://www.wright.edu/~charles.taylor/descartes/meditation5.html) :

> "I cannot conceive a God unless as existing",

translated from the [original Latin](http://www.wright.edu/~charles.taylor/descartes/meditation5l.html) :

> "ne possim quidem cogitare Deum nisi existentem".